# Looking for an example of posting to a REST api using JSON with Javascript only

Tags: javascript, rest, post

Looking for a JavaScript only example of taking input from a form and calling a rest APIusing a POST.   Everything I find uses jQuery.

Comment: Which part are you stuck on? There are any number of vanilla JS Ajax tutorials online.

Comment: You can also use axios which provides a clean api, can you provide some details of what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("POST", "/your/url/here");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
xmlhttp.send(
    JSON.stringify({f1:"v1", f2:123})
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The  Official WebSite W3School provides many example for [AJAX with Pure JS .](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)

You could check it. Anyway, I like to wrap this AJAX call in function to be able to reuse it for many URLs .

```
function simpleAjax(method,url,params,fnback){
            method=method || "GET";
             let xh=new XMLHttpRequest();
             with(xh){
                 setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");

                  if(fnback){ // Async Call
                        open(method, url,true);
                        send(JSON.stringify(parmas));
                        onreadystatechange= fnback.call(xh,xh.responseText)
                   }else{ //SYNC Call
                           open(method, url);
                           send(JSON.stringify(parmas));
                           return xh;
                    }


              }

}
```

Then ,call it:

- **Sync** :

  ```
   var  request=simpleAjax('POST','/rest/my/url',{id:23});
   //console.log(request.responseText) ;
  ```
- **Async**

  ```
   simpleAjax('POST','/rest/my/url',{id:23},function(response){
        console.log(response);
    })
  ```

Comment: *"The Official WebSite W3School"* - In what sense is it "official"? It's not in any way connected with the W3.